# React WebPack Live Update not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I was doing a course on ES6 and react. I just finished the ES6 modules and lessons my live updates were working. Hit command S on mac keyboard and the page was updated.

Now I went into terminal and installed a few react things and I am noticing that I am still connecting to my local 3000 host server with npm start. But its not live updated. I'll have for example this code and I have to close my terminal run another npm start then my code will be updated. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong? If theres any information you need I will edit in the info thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Global extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> Hi </h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Global;
```

Comment: It is not abnormal. Sometimes your reactjs app in  the browser could lose connection to the hot reload server. Refreshing the page will fix it.

Comment: Please, could you provide more info about your package.json and webpack config ?